# Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Call dropped by load balancing policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I set up a persistent and secured REST server using Docker for a hyperledger composer business network as of this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

However when I try to carry out a ping on the RESTful API I get the following error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Call dropped by load balancing policy",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Call dropped by load balancing policy\n    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:713:34)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

my docker containers:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                    NAMES
bc602ba11578        myorg/my-composer-rest-server                                                                                               "pm2-docker composer…"   15 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       192.168.0.4:3000->3000/tcp                               rest
36775102dbb0        mongo                                                                                                                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       192.168.0.4:27017->27017/tcp                             mongo
e0de4ec135fa        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-block-aviation-network-0.16.3-77a9550c9adb2621d28c3143c0fc904fa6a78013fef37bee1fdf4f2aeb8bf564   "chaincode -peer.add…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                             dev-peer0.org1.example.com-block-aviation-network-0.16.3
072f3da47cca        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                                        "peer node start --p…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    192.168.0.4:7051->7051/tcp, 192.168.0.4:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
9534c540fa89        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                                     "tini -- /docker-ent…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 192.168.0.4:5984->5984/tcp           couchdb
10ec1d267dee        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                                          "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    192.168.0.4:7054->7054/tcp                               ca.org1.example.com
85d19b25d5af        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                                     "orderer"                About an hour ago   Up About an hour    192.168.0.4:7050->7050/tcp
```

gRPC trace on REST server when carrying out transaction:

```
    0|composer |     at <anonymous>
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.163475716      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  SEND_INITIAL_METADATA{key=3a 70 61 74 68 ':path' value=2f 70 72 6f 74 6f 73 2e 45 76 65 6e 74 73 2f 43 68 61 74 '/protos.Events/Chat', key=3a 61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 74 79 ':authority' value=31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e 30 2e 34 3a 37 30 35 33 '192.168.0.4:7053'} RECV_INITIAL_METADATA
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.163524192      16 client_channel.c:1421]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: entering combiner
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.163537485      16 client_channel.c:298]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: starting name resolution
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.163556276      16 client_channel.c:1108]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: deferring pick pending resolver result
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.163579364      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  RECV_TRAILING_METADATA
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.163591158      16 client_channel.c:1421]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: entering combiner
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.175539481      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  SEND_MESSAGE:flags=0x00000000:len=833
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.175607947      16 client_channel.c:1421]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: entering combiner
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.190371761      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d8f0040]:  SEND_INITIAL_METADATA{key=3a 70 61 74 68 ':path' value=2f 70 72 6f 74 6f 73 2e 45 6e 64 6f 72 73 65 72 2f 50 72 6f 63 65 73 73 50 72 6f 70 6f 73 61 6c '/protos.Endorser/ProcessProposal', key=3a 61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 74 79 ':authority' value=31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e 30 2e 34 3a 37 30 35 31 '192.168.0.4:7051'} SEND_MESSAGE:flags=0x00000000:len=1033 SEND_TRAILING_METADATA{} RECV_INITIAL_METADATA RECV_MESSAGE RECV_TRAILING_METADATA
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190481906      16 client_channel.c:1421]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: entering combiner
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190531681      16 client_channel.c:298]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: starting name resolution
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190573660      16 client_channel.c:1108]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: deferring pick pending resolver result
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.190743276      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  RECV_MESSAGE
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190768963      16 client_channel.c:1421]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: entering combiner
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190887403      16 client_channel.c:370]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: got resolver result: error="No Error"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190906094      16 pick_first.c:687]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d33a0 created.
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.190918988      16 pick_first.c:335]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d33a0 received update with 1 addresses
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.190949872      16 pick_first.c:416]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d33a0 created subchannel 0x559d8d6e6880 for address uri ipv4:192.168.0.4:7053
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190965564      16 client_channel.c:477]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: resolver result: lb_policy_name="pick_first" (changed), service_config="(null)"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.190980957      16 client_channel.c:559]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: initializing new LB policy
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191000247      16 client_channel.c:248]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: setting connectivity state to IDLE
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191013141      16 client_channel.c:1092]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: resolver returned, doing pick
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191023036      16 client_channel.c:940]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: applying service config to call
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191032231      16 client_channel.c:1178]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: starting pick on lb_policy=0x559d8d8d33a0
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191047124      16 pick_first.c:469]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d33a0 connectivity changed. Updating selected: 0; Updating subchannels: 0; Checking 0 index (1 total); State: 4; 
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191067613      16 client_channel.c:262]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: lb_policy=0x559d8d8d33a0 state changed to SHUTDOWN
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191095699      16 client_channel.c:248]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: setting connectivity state to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191106894      16 client_channel.c:1160]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: pick completed asynchronously
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191134680      16 client_channel.c:1015]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: failed to create subchannel: error={"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191145674      16 client_channel.c:897]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: failing 4 pending batches: {"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.191160467      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191172061      16 client_channel.c:1403]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: failing batch with error: {"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.191196349      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191210942      16 client_channel.c:1403]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: failing batch with error: {"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.191225035      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191235329      16 client_channel.c:1403]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: failing batch with error: {"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.191247323      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d898580]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191265314      16 client_channel.c:1403]      chand=0x559d8d8d6860 calld=0x559d8d8985a0: failing batch with error: {"created":"@1516281277.191116289","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.191287004      16 pick_first.c:100]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d33a0 destroyed.
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197227632      16 client_channel.c:370]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: got resolver result: error="No Error"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197257617      16 pick_first.c:687]           Pick First 0x559d8d8f4880 created.
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.197270111      16 pick_first.c:335]           Pick First 0x559d8d8f4880 received update with 1 addresses
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.197298596      16 pick_first.c:416]           Pick First 0x559d8d8f4880 created subchannel 0x559d8d84e8c0 for address uri ipv4:192.168.0.4:7051
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197313289      16 client_channel.c:477]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: resolver result: lb_policy_name="pick_first" (changed), service_config="(null)"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197361765      16 client_channel.c:559]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: initializing new LB policy
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197392849      16 client_channel.c:248]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: setting connectivity state to IDLE
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197410840      16 client_channel.c:1092]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: resolver returned, doing pick
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197424333      16 client_channel.c:940]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: applying service config to call
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197445423      16 client_channel.c:1178]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: starting pick on lb_policy=0x559d8d8f4880
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197464613      16 pick_first.c:469]           Pick First 0x559d8d8f4880 connectivity changed. Updating selected: 0; Updating subchannels: 0; Checking 0 index (1 total); State: 4; 
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197486302      16 client_channel.c:262]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: lb_policy=0x559d8d8f4880 state changed to SHUTDOWN
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197525183      16 client_channel.c:248]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: setting connectivity state to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197540675      16 client_channel.c:1160]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: pick completed asynchronously
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197571460      16 client_channel.c:1015]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: failed to create subchannel: error={"created":"@1516281277.197554968","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197587652      16 client_channel.c:897]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: failing 1 pending batches: {"created":"@1516281277.197554968","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.197609941      16 client_channel.c:1383]      OP[client-channel:0x559d8d8f0040]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1516281277.197554968","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197632329      16 client_channel.c:1403]      chand=0x559d8d8d29e0 calld=0x559d8d8f0060: failing batch with error: {"created":"@1516281277.197554968","description":"Call dropped by load balancing policy","file":"../src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.c","file_line":1011}
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197665513      16 pick_first.c:100]           Pick First 0x559d8d8f4880 destroyed.
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197695598      16 client_channel.c:370]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: got resolver result: error="No Error"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197712689      16 pick_first.c:687]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d07c0 created.
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.197726782      16 pick_first.c:335]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d07c0 received update with 1 addresses
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.197762464      16 pick_first.c:416]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d07c0 created subchannel 0x559d8d6e6880 for address uri ipv4:192.168.0.4:7053
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197782454      16 client_channel.c:477]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: resolver result: lb_policy_name="pick_first", service_config="(null)"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197800745      16 client_channel.c:559]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: initializing new LB policy
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.197816437      16 client_channel.c:248]       chand=0x559d8d8d6860: setting connectivity state to IDLE
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.199036527      16 client_channel.c:370]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: got resolver result: error="No Error"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.199060715      16 pick_first.c:687]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d0540 created.
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.199071509      16 pick_first.c:335]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d0540 received update with 1 addresses
0|composer | I0118 13:14:37.199094498      16 pick_first.c:416]           Pick First 0x559d8d8d0540 created subchannel 0x559d8d84e8c0 for address uri ipv4:192.168.0.4:7051
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.199117886      16 client_channel.c:477]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: resolver result: lb_policy_name="pick_first", service_config="(null)"
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.199131080      16 client_channel.c:559]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: initializing new LB policy
0|composer | D0118 13:14:37.199142074      16 client_channel.c:248]       chand=0x559d8d8d29e0: setting connectivity state to IDLE
0|composer | Unhandled error for request POST /api/OurSetupDemo: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Call dropped by load balancing policy
0|composer |     at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:713:34)
0|composer |     at <anonymous>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm.. a quick search seems to suggest that this is a grpc issue (based on the error message 'Error: Call dropped by load balancing policy",' https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12506 - but have you used the same exported card to connect to the business network through playground for example?  What does `composer card list -c user@my-network` reveal ? - does it show 'Credentials Not Set' or are they set (in which case you can export that to use in your REST client -ie replacing the names above with your user/network) ?  Did you import the exported card (file..browser..exported .card file) into your REST client first ? Then check with a /GET WALLET to see it was set? Then do a `GET /system/ping` as per https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html

Comment: I saw that it could be an issue with grpc but I think that was only for older versions of go. I'm using go v 1.9.2 which this shouldn't apply to. I haven't been using the playground - I have been just using the cli to interact with the blockchain. 

Yeah when I do a `composer card list -c admin@block-aviation-network` it says credentials and secret are set. It says that its roles are none though? Then if I do a GET WALLET on the rest server I get:
 `"name": "admin@block-aviation-network",
    "default": true`

So it looks like the identity is on the network...

Comment: If do a `GET /system/ping` on the rest server I get same error as above..

Comment: grpc is used between the rest server and the fabric, the version we currently use is 1.6.6 and golang version isn't relevant in this case. I've seen this error I think only once and it turned out to be a problem specific to the user's environment but the grpc error message is not really helpful. You could try turning on grpc tracing to see if that helps, if not try uninstalling the rest server and re-installing to see if it was a grpc install problem. Also check you have enough resources such as memory.

Comment: Thanks @david_k do you know how to turn on grpc tracing on a hyperledger network?

Comment: I saw these in a github issue which may help
GRPC_TRACE=client_channel,pick_first,round_robin,glb
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG

Comment: Afraid it doesn't mean much to me. All I can think is that your environment has come sort of connectivity problem and grpc is reporting some spurious error rather than anything useful. You could try changing the level of grpc yourself and see if it then reports a different and more useful error.

Comment: I didn't find a complete fix to this issue but if you restart all your containers the issue goes away - it still comes back sometimes though